# SQL 2008 R2 replication with Oracle DB Server Issue

Tags: sql, replication, oracle

I am configuring replication between SQL 2008 R2 & Oracle DB server. 
Getting below error

"ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string (Source: MSSQL_REPL_ORACLE, Error number: 1830)
Get help:

in replication monitor window of SQLServer - Replication - Local Publication  - My DB - Replication Monitor - Distribution to Subscriber history.

Can any one have the idea on this?
Not sure what could be the issue.

Thanks,
Sandesh

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running into the issue described in this KB Article:  [FIX: A column that uses the DATETIME data type does not replicate to an Oracle subscriber by using a transactional replication in SQL Server 2008, in SQL Server 2008 R2 or in SQL Server 2012](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2445812)

Apply the appropriate Cumulative Update or Service Pack and see if that alleviates your issue.